# Casting and adding pointers to types of different size

Tags: c, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

Suppose I have following code snippet:

```
int8_t *a = 1;
int16_t *b = (int16_t*)(a + 1);
int32_t *c = (int32_t*)b + 2;
```

Then a = 1, b = 2, c = 10. 
(Here I am not sure either, because I used printf() with %i and I got a warning about this.)

I am not quite sure how this works. I have some theories, but I prefer to read some documentation about it.

Can someone give me a key word to search for or explain the exact behaviour in this three cases to me? I wasn't able to find information on this matter on SO or google for lack of a word to search for.

Will the output change when I type

```
int16_t *a = 1;
int32_t *b = (int16_t*)(a + 1);
int64_t *c = (int32_t*)b + 2;
```

instead?

Comment: Key word: Pointer arithmetics.

Comment: @alk: Thanks! I was able to find a good guide about pointer arithmetics through your help, see http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/BitOp/pointer.html, section "The Type's the thing"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your whole program is undefined behaviour, because I'm not sure if it is valid to put arbitrary values into pointer variables or to output them with `%i`.

That said, I think most environments are ok with it, so I think I can start to explain.

If `a` is `1`, it (misalignedly) points to the memory address `1`.
Then you add 1, so that it points to `2`, and cast the result to fit into `b`.

After that, you bake `b` a `uint32_t *` and add 2, so effectively you add `2*4` and thus get make `b` point to `10 (0xA)`.

If you do the said changes, your `a` points to `1` (and `2`, as it has 16 bits), adding `1` will make `b` point to `3` (and `4`) (the cast is not needed there), and `c` will point to 3+2*4 = 11.

Comment: I think assigning arbitrary values to pointers is perfectly defined, and about the output problem I was unsure myself. How can I output the pointer correctly? Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @mcwise For pointers you have `%p`, or you can cast them to `int`, `long` or whatever seems fit, and use the respective formatting option.

Comment: Alright, thanks. Also, referring to this http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~myers/cgs4406/notes/pointers.html you are right, and it is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than a specific question like this you should probably try to gain more understanding of the language itself (pointers, dereference etc) http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/

Assigning a value to a pointer is like saying this pointer represents the memory at address (value).

```
int8_t * a = 1; // a is memory at address 1
int16_t *b = (int16_t*)(a + 1); // b is memory at address (a + 1)... 2
int32_t *c = (int32_t*)b + 2; // c is memory at address 2 + (2 * sizeof(int32_t))... 10
```

Comment: I'm talking C not C++ but still I think you're right. Although, I have the feeling that when it comes to C it's all about details but it's quite hard to learn about details.
Edit: I found this: http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~myers/cgs4406/notes/pointers.html it seems about a good introduction.